How might one attempt to recover a fully drained NiMH cell?
While the particular devices in this question are "consumer" NiMH cells; I am looking for a general answer, based on electrical engineering principles, that applies also to "non-consumer" NiMH cells (i.e., parts one would buy for a project one is building oneself) as well. The exemplar of the problem I'm giving involves consumer devices, but I mention them specifically only to make sure I'm giving as accurate detail as possible on my measurements, and exposing any misconceptions I may have about how (or even if) the cells were drained.
I have a set of four modern rechargeable NiMH AA cells that I left in a 1980s portable computer (a Cambridge Z88, from 1987) and then forgot about for a while.
When I took it off the shelf today, I discovered that it had completely drained three of the cells, which now measure 0 V across the terminals; the fourth one measures 0.7 V. When I put any of those three 0 V ones in my charger, the charger says "Err."
Is it possible that fully drained cells like this are recoverable? If so, how would I attempt do that? I have standard bench power supplies available, and I'm able to construct constant-current sources with an LM317 or the like.
I also note that the fourth cell, at 0.7 V, is well below the suggested full discharge level of 0.9-1.0 V, and may have been damaged, though my charger did start to charge it. I'm also open to comments on the damage this may have suffered.

Can they be recovered at all or how poor their performance will be after recovering depends on how damaged they already are. So the answer is just generic yes or no and it depends on if your batteries can or cannot be recovered.

@Andyaka No. I already know that I've gone well below the voltage at which the cells should be considered "empty"; my question is, to what degree can I recover from this situation?

@Justme "...it depends on if your batteries can or cannot be recovered." Sure. So how can I tell if these particular batteries can be recovered or not?

@cjs Try to recover them and you know. They might be shorted with dendrites that either burn off or don't. They also might have lost a significant amount of their capacity, so they are practically unusable, so it's up to you to determine if that counts as recovered or not.

to what degree can I recover from this situation <-- nobody on-line can tell you that answer.

@Andyaka No, they can't give me the exact answer, but they can tell me how these things generally work and how to determine it for myself. (It appears that you can't, but I'm sure that others can.)

@Justme "Try to recover them and you know. [sic]" I'm sorry, could you please read my question again, particularly the part where I specifically ask, "how would I do that?" The caviling of you two is doing absolutely nothing to get towards an answer to any of my questions here. Step up or step off, please.

This post was discussed on meta.

You can try to revive the batteries with a standard bench supply that has settable output voltage and current limit.
People usually try to revive discharged cells by shorting them with wires to a good and charged cell, but bench supply is more controlled way to do it.
As NiMH cells have very low output impedance due to their very low ESR, use thick wires that don't melt under the possible 10-20A of battery current. Fortunately most bench supplies are limited to around 3A so banana plug wires will do fine.
Set the voltage to something like 1V to 1.5V and max current limit, 3A. Charge the battery for 1 to 3 seconds and see if it charges again in a smart charger.
If the battery does not charge, try again or try trickle charging with low current like C/20 until voltage rises to a level your charger allows it to charge.
If the voltage does not rise much, the battery may have formed dendrites that short the terminals. In this case maybe paralleling it with another battery for a few seconds may burn the dendrites and allows the cell to charge. Another cell can provide a very high current in the order of 10 to 20A.
Please note that this is just a theoretical approach and the actual current values, voltages and times how long to short the battery to another will vary, as there are no official specifications for how to try reviving a dead cell.
The last thing you want is a charged battery ready to be shorted by an internal dendrite. NiMH batteries rarely burn up or explode, but they might heat up a lot. So just as a disclaimer, you can try, but I am not sure if you should try to revive dead NiMH batteries.

Thanks; this is the type of answer I was looking for! But just so I'm absolutely clear, since we're talking about relatively large currents here, by "paralleling" you're saying that the positive terminal of a good cell should be connected to the positive terminal of the dead cell, and negative to negative, right?

@cjs Yes, that's how you transfer charge from one battery to another. Same as jump starting a car with another battery. Doing it the other way around would just do more damage to the empty cell, discharging it even further and charging it in reverse.

I have heard at least one personal account (from a very trusted source) of an NiCd battery exploding just from being shorted so I suggest caution in pulsing. As a kid I (foolishly) tried rejuvenating  zinc-carbon cells and found the carbon rods would sometimes become projectiles. All good fun and I still have both eyes, but not everyone is lucky.

@SpehroPefhany Thank you! I will take extra precautions when trying this. (If indeed I do; I am still considering, based on what I've learned from these answers, whether or not I should make an attempt.)

Discharging a large capacitor would be safer because the energy is limited, but huge low voltage "computer grade" capacitors are no longer common. One thing that can happen is that you intend a brief connection but it welds on contact and you get more energy than expected going into a sealed can with liquid inside.

Some years back I ordered a number of NiMH AA cells from a (generally) reputable supplier.  It seems that they had been in store for a while as many of them measured 0V or close to.  I found that some but not all of them could be recovered using a bench supply with current limit set to about 200mA.  A few went to dead short, others just wouldn’t hold charge.
To be clear to all readers: absolutely don’t do this with lithium cells; if they go under voltage then there are serious safety concerns with trying to recharge them.

Noting that SOME LiIon cells with protection circuitry included will drop to zero terminal voltage if the cell potential drops below the V_low limit. The actual cell voltage may be only very slightly below this limit and may remain in that range for a long while. In such cases the cell MAY be able to be safely and usefully revived by applying a trickle-up current. From memory C/10 may often be suggested, but lower will probably work also. || With Lithium cells in all situations my advice is to be adequately informed of the issues and then to take suitable precautions to address them.

... Incorrectly treated Li batteries can self destruct with substantial energy release and intense heat and flame. IF  users are aware of this and make suitable allowances AND understand what proper treatment is then such occurrences will be infrequent, and more annoying and possibly expensive than dangerous. || That said, with inadequate understanding and improper handling substantial destruction can occur.
